# iOS: Draw text on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, mkmapview

I am looking for a way to draw text on a MKMapView.  The text is needed to label some buildings on our campus, which I have already marked with a MKPolygon, but I would also like to add a text label.

Is this possible using a UILabel in a custom annotation? Or is another method better?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing stopping you from adding a UILabel as a subview to the MKMapView.

Comment: Sure, I can do this. But it needs to be more like an annotation, which will resize and move like it is anchored to the map.